# JQuery: How to select label of input's ancestor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```html
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label-sub">Description/Pack Size</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" name="packetSize" class="wfinput required form_error" id="packetSize" />
    <label id="packetSize-error" class="form_error" for="packetSize">
      This field is required.
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to select the `<label>` element that is the child of `.control-group` (ie, the one with "Description/Pack Size" text), from the `<input />` text field in my HTML?

Comment: use: `.parent()`

Comment: It's `.prev()` not `.parent()`

Comment: You have to show what you have tried so far, it's unclear what your difficulty is. Also, avoid screenshots, actual code is much better

Comment: For reference, see [Tree Traversal](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) and [Traversing & Manipulating](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/traversing-manipulating).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the `<label>` element that is above the `<input/>` element, you could:

1. first use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to select the first `.control-group` above the `<input/>` element and then
2. select the first child label of that `.control-group`

This can be achieved via the following jQuery script:

```
const input = $('input[name="packetSize"]');

const controlGroup = input.closest('.control-group');

const label = $('label', controlGroup);
```

It's possible to condense this into a single line but I've broken it into steps for clarity. Hope that helps.

Comment: I want to start to the inputFieldId ( imagine so many input field)

Comment: I want to select the label element, using the inputElement

Comment: Dacre, you should teach the OP how to ask questions, you are guessing what they want to do but OP had not provided enough info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all label that class was named "control-label-sub".

```
var element = $("label.control-label-sub")
```

And If you want to get only that label I prefer following

```
var element = $("input#packetSize").parent().prev()
```